# What does a naval route's risk rate mean to me?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I'm catching up on the naval missions and so far all of them listed the route's risk rate (starting at 80% and going down as I finish missions) and the reward (lowering the risk by 25%).

Why does it matter? Does it somehow affect the rest of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually you'll be able to construct naval transports (this is why you have "land convoys" instead of just "convoys") - the risk on your routes will apply to trading runs in much the same manner as with wagons.